# Manipulate Managed Package Dom On Managed Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, javascript, managed-package

Is there a way to use javascript to manipulate the dom of a managed package vfpage? If for example I do an apex include to include the manage packaged page on my own page and add my own script to that page?

I have a data table from a managed package that I would like to include additional information on but the actual page itself is non-editable. I'm wondering if there is a way to circumvent this via javascript and add the columns I need to the dom manually with my data.

Comment: I would say this is hypothetically possible, but it might just be easier to copy-paste the original page and then make your modifications there.

Comment: The page is available for includes but it contains various components that are not visible as it is packaged so I can't copy and paste the content. My issue right now is my script is not able to find the content within the iframe of the vfpage.